# Cubic function: Sign of the range (Precalculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the function $(x-1)(x-2)(x+1)\le0$ I found that $y=0$ when $x$ is either $-1, 1$ or $2$.

Now I have issues finding if $y$ is positive or negative when $x$ is between $1$ and $2$. By plotting above function I can see that $y$ is negative when $x$ is between $1$ and $2$, but when I replace $\frac12$ ($x$ value between $1$ and $2$) in the above function I got $\frac98$ which is "positive" but it is not $\le0$:
$$(x-1)(x-2)(x+1)\le0$$
$$(1/2-1)(1/2-2)(1/2+1)\le0$$
$$(-1/2)(-3/2)(3/2)\le0$$
$$(9/8)\le0$$
So, I don't know how to calculate sign of the range (if $y$ is positive or negative) of the cubic function in this case. For other ranges (less than $1$ and greater than $2$) I was able to correctly calculate sign (if $y$ is positive or negative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac12$ is not between $1$ and $2$. You should have tried something like $\frac32$ instead, which evaluates to $-\frac58$.

Comment: We all have those moments...

Comment: Ahhh....  so embarrassing...  yes, I should take 3/2 instead :)

Answer (score 0):

The function ''comes from below and goes to above'' if you consider its graph since the polynomial has odd degree and positive leading coefficient; i.e., the function is negative below $-1$, it is positive between $-1$ and $1$, it is negative between $1$ and $2$ and positive above $2$. My Eileen, 11th grade, can draw such a function.

So its positive between $-1$ and $1$. Your calculation for $x=1/2$ is correct.